# Is there any way to alter add table column in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

Table name is `TestTable`. How can I add a new column to the table which is hold in markAtrr variable?

Means how can I perform this query in django?

```
ALTER TABLE table_name 
ADD column_name column_definition; 


    def createTest(request):
        markAttr=request.POST.get('Attr')
        obj=TestTable()
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel you need to read the documentation harder, or work through the tutorials again.

A django Model subclass describes a database table. After you have created it for the first time you run the management commands

```
./manage.py makemigrations
```

and if there are no errors to fix,

```
./manage.py migrate
```

this latter creates a new table for your app in the database, connected to your model definition.

If you want to add a column to that model (or delete a column, or change the attributes of a column) you editing the model definition to add a field (column definition) and then again `makemigrations` and upon success, `migrate`. Your forms, views etc. can then be modified to use the column/field which migration has added or altered.

Comment: how can I perform this query in django-              
  ALTER TABLE table_name
  ADD column_name column_definition;